# Programação no MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Estou com uma simulação pronta no MATLAB e cada vez que eu rodar preciso salvar o resultado. Que comando uso pra salvar cada resultado separadamente e depois juntar todos e ver que curva se ajusta a esses resultados ?

Comment: Poderia mostra um pequeno pedaço do seu problema?Vc está salvando em que formato de arquivo o .mat?

Answer (score 2):

A simulação é no próprio Matlab ou dentro do Simulink. Caso seja no Simulink há como configurar o Scope (gráfico para salvar). Caso seja em código do Matlab, pode colocar a simulação dentro de um laço e salvar a cada iteração os resultado como colunas de uma matriz ou elementos de uma lista. Após isso, verificam-se ajustes de curva. Caso esteja procurando por funções polinomiais, use o `polyfit`.

Forneça mais detalhes do seu problema, por favor.